# Official Transcripts: Applying to Previous University

Tags: graduate-school, application, university, transcript-of-records

I am applying for Graduate Admissions to the Previous University where I graduated nearly 10 years ago.

Application says to send official copies of Transcripts from Previous University.

But I am applying to Previous University, shouldn't they have it?

Sure, I can upload photocopies of their transcripts (application process is online only), but what else do I need to do?

How do I address this in application?

How do I tell them "I am uploading copies of Transcript, but you already have official Transcript"

Thanks!

#### Ok

I'll request official transcripts and return it back to them

Comment: Whether they have it or not, including a copy will make the admissions office's job much easier. If at all possible, follow the instructions.

Comment: @keshlam I updated question. Sure, I'll upload copies, but how to tell them they already have Official Transcripts?

Comment: You don't need to tell them anything!... Just behave like a typical applicant...

Comment: So in other words, request one department of the University send itself official copies of transcripts.

Comment: You know, in some countries it could be illegal for the admissions committee to access your transcripts without you handing them over.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In keeping with the tone of the existing answer and the comments:

**Just do what the application instructions say.**

*In the best case*, the university agrees that you do not need to send the transcript. You have saved yourself about 5 minutes of work.

*In the worst case*, your application is desk-rejected by an overzealous clerk. You never even find out why.

*In a plausible middle-of-the-road case*, you need to send some clarifying mails back and forth about why you haven't included the transcript. You initially saved 5 minutes of work, and then spent 30 minutes. Worse, somebody else *also* needs to spend some time on this.

Frankly, even writing this question probably already took longer than *just sending the transcripts*.

Comment: So in other words, upload copies of Transcripts, and then request the University send itself Official Copies?

Comment: @SohniMahiwal, no. Just add the official transcripts as everybody else does.

Answer (score 4):

As the comments say, you make the applications office job easier by getting them through the regular channels, and forward them as anybody else would do.

At least around here, the graduate admissions office is quite separate from undergraduate affairs, so it would be a significant hassle for them to ask for transcripts. They might even be pissed off enough to just file your application under "incomplete" in the round archive.